# How to upload an iWork Pages 5.2 file.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iwork

Apple has changed the way it manages iWork files. The files are now a bundle with contents much like their Apps. I need to create an upload form that can receive a number of files. Mainly images but some Pages and Numbers too. The dropped files could number up to 15 and will be sorted server side using PHP. That is already built.

My question is.

How can i get the Pages files to upload? So far I have tried lots of pre built solutions.

I have also been building from scratch. "dataTransfer" doesn't like it, it says it is a directory. 
FileReader sees it but when I try to do the following

```
for  (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            var entry = items[i].type;

            if (entry == "image/png" || entry.type == "image/jpg" || entry.type == "image/jpeg" ) {
                formData.append("file" + i , items[i]);

            } else {

                var fileReader = new FileReader(); 
                var binary = fileReader.readAsBinaryString(items[i]);
                var blob = new Blob([binary], {type: blob});
                formData.append("file" + i , blob);
```

it returns undefined and pops the following error `"failed to load resource      blob:http://localhost/<RANDOM BLOB STRING HERE>"`

When I decode the blob server side, unsurprisingly I get a file with 0Kb size so its never going.

I really just want to get all the files into a folder on the server. I don't even mind if I have to send a server request per file as inefficient as it may be.

I have also tried base64 encode and again i get similar results. 
I have also tried XHR.response "blob" methods too. In each case I do not get my file or i get a corrupted version.

What is the best way to attack this?

Answer (score 0):

.Pages "files" are a folder with files. OSX will display them as a single file; other systems will likely see them as a folder. Either way, other systems probably won't be able to open them anyway,

I ran into this issue a few years ago attempting to load them into a version control system. Best work-around I found was to zip the file and than version control it. Not great, but it did work.

Best solution, honestly, is to avoid .Pages. It isn't really a well recognized format, so may users won't be able to open it anyway. Pages can convert to a more recognized Word or RTF format.

As a side note, you may want to be very careful handling files like that (blob). I don't see anything preventing someone from uploading a malicious PHP script or other harmful files...

Comment: Agreed it is a pain but i am bound by it. And adding a step to the user workflow of zipping prior to upload is not an option either. There must be a way to get this file server side.

Comment: @GlennHolland If this is an internal tool (and security isn't a huge concern) than perhaps upload the entire directory (there are some Javascript tools for it) and zip it on the server?